# ReCAPTCHA throwing error when used inside jQuery Stepy Wizard

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, recaptcha, jquery-form-wizard

I have used multi step sign up form using jQuery.stepy.js Also I have added google ReCAPTCHA using 'gem "recaptcha"'. When I am placing

```
  <%= recaptcha_tags %>
```

inside wizard form it is throwing JavaScript error like this:

```
Uncaught Error: ReCAPTCHA placeholder element must be empty
```

I have searched for the reason behind this error and found that this error occurs if the google recaptcha library is loading twice.
Is this happening because of jQuery.stepy.js ? How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Does this error occur if you remove the `<%= recaptcha_tags %>`? Can you show the full error script from the browser's javascript console?

Comment: No, the error doesn't occur if I remove the <%= recaptcha_tags %>. Full error is:
Uncaught Error: ReCAPTCHA placeholder element must be empty
    at Wp (recaptcha__en.js:394)
    at recaptcha__en.js:399
    at Jp (recaptcha__en.js:389)
    at recaptcha__en.js:398
    at recaptcha__en.js:410
Wp @ recaptcha__en.js:394
(anonymous) @ recaptcha__en.js:399
Jp @ recaptcha__en.js:389
(anonymous) @ recaptcha__en.js:398
(anonymous) @ recaptcha__en.js:410

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when `recaptcha/api.js` file gets loaded multiple times.

In your case you have used <%= recaptcha_tag %>, this tag inject api.js by default everytime it renders. Just check you haven't added the library file explicitly or using multiple recaptcha tags (each one will inject library script).

You can set `:script` param to `false`, by passing argument to method:

```
<%= recaptcha_tag :script => false %>
```